# org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.11:

Tags: java, spring-mvc, salesforce

I am working on **Spring MVC + Salesforce Integration** from the link : https://github.com/jottley/spring-social-salesforce . I haven't done any customization changes yet, but seeing below error during compilation. What's the issue ?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.11:check (default) on project spring-social-salesforce: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: C:\REST\spring-social-salesforce\target\rat.txt -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.11:check (default) on project spring-social-salesforce: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: C:\REST\spring-social-salesforce\target\rat.txt
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.rat.mp.RatCheckException: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: C:\REST\spring-social-salesforce\target\rat.txt
        at org.apache.rat.mp.RatCheckMojo.check(RatCheckMojo.java:194)
        at org.apache.rat.mp.RatCheckMojo.execute(RatCheckMojo.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Any reason to downvote ? Have you taken efforts to reply ?

Comment: I think this is exactly why you were downvoted "When I googled I found the link" as per your answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I googled I found the link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-109 and it has suggestion to compile the like below.

> mvn clean install -Drat.skip=true

Comment: I think this is exactly why you were downvoted "When I googled I found the link"

Comment: This is not how you answer. Where is your explanation?

Comment: This is still helpful, so I gave an upvote for the answer.